# Using jQuery toggle to hide/show form submit button based on checkbox being checked - how to set submit button toggled off by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, toggle

I have a form that I'm using whereby I would like to require a checkbox ('terms') to be checked in order to toggle the Submit button ('checkout-submit') on. I have it working just fine once you check the checkbox and then uncheck, etc.

But, by default the Submit button is showing. I'm unsure in my code how to ensure that the Submit button is toggled off when the page loads.

```
$('#terms').click(function() {
$("#checkout-submit").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I have made a bit of progress while sticking to toggle... I've added the .hide jQuery effect to the 'checkout-submit' button, which is nice and technically does the trick.

    $('#checkout-submit').hide();
    $('#terms').click(function() {
    $("#checkout-submit").toggle(this.checked);
    });

The only remaining issue is that for a split second while the page is loading you can see the submit button before it is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to put the boolean attribute `required` on the checkbox, like so

```
<input type="checkbox" required>
```

Then if the user attempts to submit without checking the box, a native html5 dialog (which looks quite nice) appears, saying you have to check the box to proceed. The user can hit submit as many times as they like, but nothing will happen until the checkbox is checked. Note that all of this has to be inside a `form` element.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, we're not ever actually "submitting" the form, but rather triggering some custom script to process the form. So it doesn't make it to the step where it would check whether the box is checked. Otherwise, this would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty common to just call `e.preventDefault()` on the form submission handler, and then run the custom script. I work on single page apps a lot, so this is standard practice for me. I like taking advantage of HTML5 form validation whenever i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  $('#your_checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#your_button').removeAttr('disabled');

    } else {
        $('#your_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
//set it to disabled at load 
$('#your_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t70cc43o/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did try this after you suggested, and for some reason it isn't working for me. I've tried other similar solutions trying to set default state of the submit button to disabled, but to no avail. There may be something in the code overriding that. I'm not sure. There is quite a bit of custom script processing of the form.